# Excessive whitespace on main question feed

Tags: feature-request, design

An image speaks a thousand words:

[image: Screenshot of the top of the question feed, showing a large blank space.]

In case that's not clear enough, **can we please move the "interesting, featured, hot..." tabs inline with the "Ask Question" button and remove the whitespace around it?**